# Electric field at the centre of a hemispherical shell

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, integration

To find out the electric field at the centre of the hemispherical shell, I considered an elemental strip to be a ring, calculated the electric field due to it and integrated it as follows:
[image: img height = 10]

The expression of the field due to the 'ring' can be viewed [here.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elelin.html) 
The answer I obtained matched the one my textbook stated. However, I am now beginning to doubt my solution. The elemental strips I have considered are not perfect rings. It won't make a difference on an infinitesimal scale, but when we integrate the expression, I feel that the variations will get added up and cause a significant deviation from the correct answer, but that clearly is not the case. Is my solution wrong altogether? Please resolve this confusion.

Comment: "The elemental strips I have considered are not perfect rings." You could also say that the strips underneath a curve are not perfect rectangles. These errors disappear when you take the limit before you do the summation, that is when you integrate rather than performing a summation of a finite number of elements.

Comment: The last step might need looking at, shouldn't it be +2 instead of -2

Comment: @John Hunter Indeed it should. Thanks.